# Question on Sequences and Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

So, the question itself is:
On the day of her birth, 1st January 1998, Mary's grandparents invested $x$ dollars in a savings account. They continued to deposit $x$ dollars on the first day of each month thereafter. The account paid a fixed rate of $0.4\%$ interest per month. The interest was calculated on the last day of each month and added to the account.

Let $A(n)$ be the amount in Mary's account in dollars on the last day of the $n$-th month, immediately after the interest had been added.

(a) Find an expression for $A(1)$ and show that $A(2) = 1.004^2x + 1.004x $

At part (a), the answer would be:
$A(1) = 1.004x $

$A(2) = 1.004(A(1) + x) $

$A(2) = 1.004(1.004x + x) $

$A(2) = 1.004^2x + 1.004x $

However, what I can't understand is why we multiply by $1.004$ when finding $A(2)$. Shouldn't we be multiplying by the interest, which is $0.004$?

Comment: The amount in the account includes both principal and interest.  Yes, $.004A$ is the interest so you have $A+.004A=1.004A$ in total.  (I changed the tag.  "Sequences and series" relates to a subject in calculus.)

Comment: @saulspatz but why do I need to add $A + .004A$ again, I already added this month's deposit when I added $x$ in $1.004(1.004x+x)$

Comment: Every month, how much money do you actually have? You have what is there, plus what is added. $A$ is there already. Then an additional $0.004A$ is added. We are not calculating the change each month, we are calculating the total amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A(2)$ is the amount at the end of the second month.  A deposit of $x$ may made at the beginning of the first month, so after two months it has grown to $1.004^2x$.  A deposit of $x$ was also made at the beginning of the second month.  At the end of the second month it has grown to $1.004x.$  So $$A(2)=1.004^2x+1.004x$$

Does it make sense now?

Comment: Yeah it does make more sense now, thanks for explaining it, but to be sure, for example, $A(3)$ would be $1.004^3x + 1.004^2x + 1.004x$ and so on?

Comment: Yes, that's right.